# Fixing NaN error

Tags: javascript, html

I have been parsing different combinations in my code. However, I still get the NaN error. I have this timer countdown that will allow me to set a specific time of the day and it will countdown basing on the time you have now. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

The time's format is military time.

```js
function myTime1() {
  var hour = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
  var min = document.getElementById("mins").value;
  var sec = document.getElementById("sec").value;

  var timeNow = parseInt(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
  var currentDate = moment().format("DD MM YYYY");
  var timeDateNow = currentDate + " " + timeNow;
  // document.write(currentDate + " " + parseInt(hour) + ":" + parseInt(min) + ":" + parseInt(sec));



  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date(currentDate + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <input type="number" id="hrs" value="00">
  <input type="number" id="mins" value="00">
  <input type="number" id="sec" value="00">
  <input type="button" id="btnTime1" onclick="myTime1()" value="Go">

  <p id="demo"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Adriani6, what should cause for the NaN error? Please help. </3

Comment: `countDownDate` varibale return `NAN`. because you can parse invalid date in `Date()`

Comment: THANK YOU! I just changed the format of my currentDate to YYYY MM DD! Took me 3 days for this error! Very stressful! Thank you so much!

Comment: welcome. Look i've change in your  js code.now its work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeNow = parseInt(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec)
```

timeNow variable will allways be 0, use moment.js for all data casting.